# Возможно ли создать свой сайт на StackExchange?

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сайт

Скажите пожалуйста, возможно ли создать сайт со своей тематикой на Stackexchange, и если возможно, то как это сделать? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: да, возможно. этот же сайт так и был создан

Comment: можно оставить заявку на [area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched)